# Classify $ \mathbb{Z}_9\times\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_8/\langle(3,2,4)\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Since the order of $(3,2,4)$ is $12,$ the quotient group is of order $48.$
Now I have a problem. Consider $(1,0,1)+\langle(3,2,4)\rangle.$ The element is of order $ 72,$ I think. But, it's impossible you know, so I can't solve this problem.

Comment: How did you calculate its order to be $72$?

Comment: first, |(1,0,1)|=lcm(9,1,8)=72. But since <1,0,1> is in the complement of <3,2,4>, so is (1,0,1)+<3,2,4>, I think.

Comment: note that $24(1,0,1) = (24,0,24) \equiv (24,16,32) = 8(3,2,4)$.

Comment: Clearly, the group is not cyclic, and thus it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{24}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Yes, it is not cyclic and has an element of order $24$ so it must be of type $(2,24)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the quotient is an abelian group of order $48$.

The element $x:=(1,01)$ is of order $24$ in the quotient since 
$$
24(1,0,1)=(24,0,24)\equiv(24,16,32)=8(3,2,4)
$$

but if the order of $x$ was less then $24$ then by Lagrange it would
have an order dividing $24$. Since $24=2^{3}\cdot3$ $|x|\mid24$
and $x\neq24$ imply $|x|\mid12$ or $|x|\mid8$ but then $12x\equiv(0,0,0)$
or $8x\equiv(0,0,0)$ which is not the case.

Note that 
$$
24(a,b,c)=(24a,24b,24c)=(8a\cdot3,12b\cdot2,6c\cdot4)\equiv(0,0,0)
$$

so there is no element of order $48$ thus the quotient is not cyclic.

We conclude using the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian
groups that thq quotient is isomorphic to 
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{24}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}
$$